# What are " arrays, objects, iterables, booleans, numbers, normals, finites, strings, nulls, values, scalars" called in jq?

Tags: jq

`jq` manual says

> These built-ins select only inputs that are arrays, objects, iterables (arrays or objects), booleans, numbers, normal numbers, finite numbers, strings, null, non-null values, and non-iterables, respectively.

They are built-in of what? Is there a name for them? Function? Or something else? Thanks.

Comment: They are simply shorthands for `select(type == "array")` and the like, you can call them whatever you want imo

Comment: This makes more sense now. I think that this point should be documented in the manual. So are all the other shortcuts be documented in a central place (like an index).

Comment: But I don't see a `scalar` type. So they are not exact the equivalent to `select(type == something)`.

Comment: scalars are non-iterables, like strings, numbers, booleans and null. see how all builtins are defined here: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: OK. Is there a way that I can `not` and `and` these shortcuts? Of course, this does not work `jq '.[] | (!array and !object)' <<< '[[],{},1,"foo",null,true,false]'`

Comment: nah, there is not. btw, `scalars` does exactly what you want `(!array and !object)` to do.

Comment: Your Q would have likely had fewer down and close votes if you had included your code as part of your Q. (I upvoted, cause I think these kind of details need attention). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

"built-in" means "built in", that is, built into the distribution of jq.  One of the files in the jq repository used to build jq is called "builtin.jq" and can be found at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq; it includes jq-defined definitions of jq filters.

The word "filter" rather than "function" is appropriate in general because in mathematics especially, a "function" specifies exactly one output for each input, whereas this is not true of all jq filters.  Some jq filters ignore their inputs entirely; `empty` always emits nothing.

Some of the jq built-ins are not even functional in nature, notably `input` and `inputs`.